# List Objects in S3 With Wilde card/Star * pattern (Scala/Java)

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, amazon-s3

I am trying to list all the objects in my S3 bucket with a star pattern but it seems AWS SKD nor Hadoop FS doesn't support it.

first I have tried SDK:

```
val prefix = "xyz/staging/*/2020/04/05/"
val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard.withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build
val result = s3.listObjectsV2("MyBucket", prefix)
val objects = result.getObjectSummaries
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
for (os <- objects) {
  System.out.println("* " + os.getKey)
}
```

This approach returns nothing.

And then I tried Hadoop FS

```
import java.net.URI
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

val path = "s3://MyBucket/xyz/staging/*/2020/04/05/"
val fileSystem = FileSystem.get(URI.create(path), ss.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
val it = fileSystem.listFiles(new Path(path), true)
while (it.hasNext()) {
    ...
}
```

this one complaining the path doesn't exist which it does so I assume it doesn't understand the * pattern.

Comment: [ListObjectsV2 REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) does not support wildcard in prefix. In fact, none of the S3 list APIs support this.